# Implement a thread pool using GCD

Tags: ios, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, grand-central-dispatch

I have a big loop with a computational tasks which can be parallelised. For such purpose I decided to write a simple concurrent thread pool using GCD since I'm working on iOS.

My thread pool looks fairly simple. I will attach only `.m` file, it will be enough to understand my idea:

```
#import "iOSThreadPool.h"

@interface iOSThreadPool()
{
    int                                     _timeout;
    int                                     _currentThreadId;
    NSMutableArray<dispatch_queue_t>        *_pool;
    NSMutableArray<dispatch_semaphore_t>    *_semaphores;
    dispatch_group_t                        _group;
}

@end

@implementation iOSThreadPool

- (instancetype)initWithSize:(int)threadsCount tasksCount:(int)tasksCount
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _timeout = 2.0;
        _currentThreadId = 0;
        _pool = [NSMutableArray new];
        _semaphores = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++) {
            dispatch_queue_attr_t attr = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT, QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0);
            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create([NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.workerQueue_%d", i].UTF8String, attr);
            [_pool addObject:queue];

            dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(tasksCount);
            [_semaphores addObject:sema];
        }

        _group = dispatch_group_create();
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)async:(iOSThreadPoolBlock)block
{
    dispatch_group_enter(self->_group);

    __block dispatch_semaphore_t sema = _semaphores[_currentThreadId];
    dispatch_async(_pool[_currentThreadId], ^{

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(self->_timeout * NSEC_PER_SEC)));
        block();
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);

        dispatch_group_leave(self->_group);
    });

    _currentThreadId = (_currentThreadId + 1) % _pool.count;
}

- (void)wait {
    dispatch_group_wait(_group, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(self->_timeout * NSEC_PER_SEC)));
}

@end
```

So, basically when I create a thread pool I'm setting threads count and semaphore values. Since queues are concurrent I want to limit tasks count which can be executed concurrently so thread would not be overwhelmed.

The thing is - no matter how much threads I'm creating, it doesn't affect the performance at all. I guess it happens because every Dispatch Queue tasks ends up in the global queue, and no matter how many queues I have, they all send their tasks to the same `BACKGROUND` queue most of the time.

I've read a lot about `GCD` and used it a lot in my practice successfully. But when I just want to go above a simple use which you can find in countless tutorials, like perform few parallelised processes with the intention to save as much execution time as possible - I fail. And I searched for more detailed explanation or more detailed efficient techniques for `GCD`, I found nothing. It looks like 90% of the time it's used in a very simple way. And at the same time I hear that `GCD` is very very powerful multithreading framework, so clearly, I just don't know how to use it properly.

So my question is - is this really possible to launch few parallelised processes on iOS? What should I change in my thread pool to make it efficient?

NOTE: I downloaded a C++ version of `ThreadPool` based on `std::thread`. And if I change threads count in this pool, I clearly see a performance bump. I would highly appreciate if some `GCD` guru can point me how to use `GCD` at it's maximum capacity.

Comment: Why you are not using `NSOperationQueue` and `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount`? And most importantly swift

Comment: I have my reasons to write this code on Obj-C. For example, it can be mixed with C++ code. Could you ellaborate on `NSOperationQueue`? I know that it's a wrapper around `GCD` - will it have some clear advantages when performance is the key?

Comment: NSOperationQueue uses GDC a lo better than you can, you should not worry about performance

Comment: Please, elaborate a bit more. What does NSOperationQueue do in order to give me a best performance? What exactly does it do better than me? What techniques can I use to setup `NSOperationQueue` for being an efficient thread pool?

Comment: For what tasks `NSOperationQueue` is the best use, for what it doesn't? I'm sorry to say, but your answer doesn't tell me much

Comment: Please refer to apple documentation for this answers

Comment: Read Wikipedia on GCD: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch Basically, it already is an implementation of a thread pool.

Comment: Hello @Lutz! That's good point. But if you think about it - `GCD` is heavily under control with `Global Thread pool`, `QoS`, etc, which means there's not so much room to tinker in order to achieve best performance. I thought there should be some guidelines on how to communicate with `GCD` demon to make him work the way you want but I found nothing on this part. Does it mean that `GCD` is not really efficient? It's great for multithreading in terms of safety and a complexity of use, but what if I want to go above that? What if I'm interested in more than I "suppose to know"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCD already does thread pooling (dispatch queues are drawing upon a pool of “worker threads”), so it’s redundant/inefficient to add another layer of pooling on top of that.

You say:

> The thing is - no matter how much threads I'm creating, it doesn't affect the performance at all.

That could be any of a number of things. One common problem includes that the unit of work is too small. As [Performing Loops Concurrently](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW23) says:

> You should make sure that your task code does a reasonable amount of work through each iteration. As with any block or function you dispatch to a queue, there is overhead to scheduling that code for execution. If each iteration of your loop performs only a small amount of work, the overhead of scheduling the code may outweigh the performance benefits you might achieve from dispatching it to a queue.

But there are a variety of other problems ranging from inefficient synchronization code, cache sloshing, etc. It is impossible to say without a reproducible example of the problem. While QoS also has an impact, it is often negligible in comparison to these algorithmic issues.

You say:

> Since queues are concurrent I want to limit tasks count which can be executed concurrently so thread would not be overwhelmed.

While you can achieve this with either non-zero dispatch semaphores or `NSOperationQueue` with some `maxConcurrentOperationCount`, the [`dispatch_apply`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453050-dispatch_apply?language=occ) (known as [`concurrentPerform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016088-concurrentperform) for Swift users) is a “go to” solution for computationally-intensive, parallelized routines that balance workloads across CPU cores. It automatically looks at how many cores you’ve got, and distributes the loop across them, not risking an explosion in threads. And, as outlined in [Improving on Loop Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW2), you can experiment with strides that do a good job balancing the amount of work done on each thread with the inherent overhead of the thread coordination. (Striding can also minimize cache contention.)

I might suggest researching `dispatch_apply` and giving it a try. If you’re still unclear at that point, just post a new question that shows both the non-parallel routine and the parallelized rendition, and we can help further.

---

As I’ve said above, I don’t think you want this routine at all. For computationally intensive routines, I would favor `dispatch_apply`. For simple queues for which I would want to control the degree of concurrency (especially if some of those tasks are, themselves asynchronous), I’d use [`NSOperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue?language=occ) with a [`maxConcurrentOperationCount`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue/1414982-maxconcurrentoperationcount?language=objc). But I thought I’d share a few observations on your code snippet:

- What you’ve implemented is a pool of queues, not a pool of threads;
- What you’re calling `threadsCount` is not a count of threads, but rather a count of queues. So, if you create a pool with a count of 10 and `tasksCount` of 20, that means that you’re potentially using 200 threads.
- Likewise what you’re calling `_currentThreadId` is not the current thread. It’s the current queue.
- The interaction with `_currentThreadId` is not thread-safe.

Bottom line, GCD has its own pool of threads, so you shouldn’t reproduce that logic. All you need to do is to implement the “not more than `threadCount`” logic (which can be achieved with the non-zero dispatch semaphore). Thus, I’d suggest simplifying this to something like:

```
@interface ThreadPool()
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t pool;
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t scheduler;
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;
@end

@implementation ThreadPool

- (instancetype)initWithThreadCount:(int)threadCount {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSString *identifier = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
        NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

        NSString *schedulingLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.scheduler.%@", bundleIdentifier, identifier];
        _scheduler = dispatch_queue_create(schedulingLabel.UTF8String, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

        NSString *poolLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pool.%@", bundleIdentifier, identifier];

        dispatch_queue_attr_t attr = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT, QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0);
        _pool = dispatch_queue_create(poolLabel.UTF8String, attr);

        _semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(threadCount);
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)async:(ThreadPoolBlock)block {
    dispatch_async(self.scheduler, ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        dispatch_async(self.pool, ^{
            block();
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore);
        });
    });
}

@end
```

Needless to say, this implementation, like yours, assumes that the block passed to `async` method is, itself, synchronous (e.g. it’s not starting yet another asynchronous process like a network request or whatever). I suspect you know that, but I only mention it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Hello and thank you for a very nice explanation! You made it very clear!

Comment: Hello again @Rob! I just wanted to say thank you again, you filled an enormous amount of gaps in my understanding of how `GCD` works. By the way, I did use `dispatch_apply` recently and you're right - it's super efficient and very easy to integrate. Kudos!